# Problems when swapping images with fade effect

Tags: jquery

In the header of this site: http://www.ipallares.com I am trying to do some images swap, with a fade effect. It is supposed to be pretty simple jQuery but I am getting a weird behaviour. The code I am using is:

```
function changeImage(){
    var img_to_change   = Math.floor(Math.random()*99)+1
    var new_img = Math.floor(Math.random()*99)+1;
    var new_img_url = 'https://liv.s3.amazonaws.com/ipallares/images/header/'+new_img+'.jpg'; 
    jQuery("#img_"+img_to_change).fadeTo(300, 0.001, 
        function(){
            jQuery("#img_"+img_to_change).attr("src", new_img_url);
            jQuery("#img_"+img_to_change).fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
    );

    setTimeout("changeImage()", 1000);

}
```

I get the images from a directory where there are images from 1.jpg to 100.jpg.

In FF I see how (most of the times) the original image fades out (actually fades to 0.001) then fades in (actually fades to 1) and after that it changes to the new image (the image should change once the original has completely faded to 0.001 as I am using the 'complete' function callback). The new image then resizes doing an annoying effect.

In chrome it works a little better but still, randomly,  the complete function callback does not work as expected.

What am I doing wrong? I am a jQuery newbie but this is pretty simple and jQuery should be a very stable crossbrowser tool, shouldn't it?

Any workaround or advice is muche appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fZPdy/ this works fine for me. Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.8.3. Do you get it to work properly? Don't you get any resize effect? Don't you get randomly the swap image not to be faded?

Comment: I see it now, give me a second.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fZPdy/13/

You should set set the fadeIn to AFTER the image loads, or else you'll get flickering. To do this, you just need to add the fadeIn to the `load()` event:

```
$(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeIn(500); });
```

After that, you can set the source to your new image.

Comment: I think I need to use fadeTo instead of fadeOut/fadeIn, as when fading out it gets a display none which messes the pictures coming after the one being swapped. Apart from that I am doing as you say but the faded swap isn't fluent and, in FF it resizes when faded in. I think it is a little out of my reach as a frontend developer (actually I am not a frontend developer, that's why :)) as, to be done properly, I should use css sprite, and keep it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//rollover swap images with rel 
  var img_src = "";
  var new_src = "";

    $(".img-swap").hover(function(){
      //mouseover

      img_src = $(this).attr('src'); //grab original image
      new_src = $(this).attr('rel'); //grab rollover image
      $(this).attr('src', new_src); //swap images
      $(this).attr('rel', img_src); //swap images

    },
    function(){
      //mouse out

      $(this).attr('src', img_src); //swap images
      $(this).attr('rel', new_src); //swap images
    });

  //preload images
    var cache = new Array();
    //cycle through all rollover elements and add rollover img src to cache array
    $(".img-swap").each(function(){
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = $(this).attr('rel');
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

...and the HTML code should be something like:

`<img src="original.jpg" rel="rollover.jpg" class="img-swap" />`